# Data does not get inserted in some special cases?

Tags: php, mysql, database, tinymce, htmlpurifier

Here is the code I am using

```
if (!empty($_REQUEST['content'])&&!empty($_REQUEST['title'])&&!empty($_REQUEST['writer'])) {
$title = $_POST['title'];
$content = $_POST['content'];
$writer = $_POST['writer'];
require_once 'htmlpurifier/library/HTMLPurifier.auto.php';
$purifier = new HTMLPurifier();
$pure_content = $purifier->purify($content);
$entity_content = htmlentities($pure_content);
$entity_content = mysql_real_escape_string($entity_content);
mysql_query("INSERT INTO stories (TITLE, WRITER, CONTENT, UPVOTE, DOWNVOTE) VALUES ('$title', '$writer', '$content', 0, 0)");
```

Now, after some testing I found out whenever I type an apostrophe some where like it's then the values don't get inserted in table. How do I prevent this? Are there any other special characters that might cause this problem.
Here is what I am working on:  http://8mags.com/bored/people/

**Edit**

I have updated these two lines of code

```
$add_content = "INSERT INTO stories (TITLE, WRITER, CONTENT, UPVOTE, DOWNVOTE) VALUES ('$title', '$writer', '$content', 0, 0)"; 
$result = mysqli_query($mysqli, $add_content) or die(mysqli_error($mysqli));
```

Is there anything else that I need to change?

**Second Update**

I have changed this code too

```
$con = mysqli_connect($db_hostname,$db_username,$db_password);
if (!$con)
{
die('Could not connect: ' . mysqli_error());
}
mysqli_select_db($db_database, $con);
```

Is there anything else? Thank you for the help.

Comment: Dont use `mysql_*` functions.. Please check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php

Comment: I don't know, but i think the error is because you don't use the encoded contents `$entity_content` for your query... And please don't use the mysql_* functions.

Comment: If it's a true apostrophe and not a single quote, then it may have to do with your column/table set up. See if it's set up as `UTF-8`, sometimes it will fail to input or input all funky-like if not allowing certain characters.

Comment: I have updated the code to insert values in database. Is it correct or do I need to change it to something else?

Comment: You need to change the connection to the database too.

Comment: And bind parameters is required for safe queries.

Comment: Here is the link to bind parameters: http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php   Also, check your table format, it may still not accept special characters if not `UTF-8`

Comment: I have specified utf8_unicode_ci as collation for TITLE, WRITER and CONTENT. Type of Content has been set to TEXT and for others it is VARCHAR

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to put this at time of insertion.

```
$title = addslashes($_POST['title']);
$content = addslashes($_POST['content']);
$writer = addslashes($_POST['writer']);
```

And at time of show(listing)

```
stripslashes($VariableName)
```

Hope this help you.

Comment: For now it is working. Thank you!Is there any security issue that it might pose?

Comment: No no,there is no issue of security at all.

Comment: I recommend telling people to use the escaping mechanism for the medium, rather than something that works by coincidence. :) In this case, `mysql[i]_real_escape_string()` would be better than `addslashes()`, as latter solution is dependant on the MySQL server's settings. (Even better would be an introduction to parametrised prepared queries.)